# MySql select last replacement, like a chain

Tags: mysql, sql

I feel like I'm over complicating this, but for the life of me I can't seem to make this work without looping through queries and I'd like to accomplish this in a single query if possible. The replaced_by creates a chain. One record can be replaced by another record and by another record, etc. I want to retrieve the last replacement when generally querying

```
id    type    color    replaced_by
1     color   red      null
2     color   blue     3
3     color   teal     4
4     color   aqua     null
5     fruit   orange   null
```

Given the above table, I'd like to...

do a `select id, type, color` where I get the following returned

```
1     color   red
4     color   aqua
5     fruit   orange
```

do a `select id, type, color where type="color"`I get the following returned

```
1     color   red
4     color   aqua
```

or even a `select color where id="2"` and get the following returned

```
aqua
```

Comment: Hi interesting question, what would be the rules for replacing values?

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can only be done in a single query using recursive CTE, which is available in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Also do you mean to have 1 single query for all of the conditions? Or a single query for each of the condition? Make use of the `replaced_by` column. I assume that if it's not being replaced by anything it should be NULL, correct? So just do query like `WHERE replaced_by IS NULL`

Comment: You can take a look at this artocle https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/  it is about Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL If you add a root node , you can use it for your pirpose. The Select statements get sometimes tricky

Comment: As @tcadidot0 noted, you seem to have a situation where replace_by equals null for fields that are active, if replaced_by is not null it should be ignored. You also have an error in your sample because color red should probably be replaced by 2 and not null.

Comment: @tcadidot0 mysql 5.7, 1 query for each condition, yes replaced_by would be null if no replacements... it's the funnel that I'm after. I don't want the values of id 2 because it's been replaced_by id=3 and I don't want the values of id=3 because it's been replaced by id=4 but id=4 has no replacements so the chain stops there.

Comment: @Barmar this looks like the ticket! but I'm using 5.7 :-(

Comment: @azcc something like this perhaps? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/T5WdgqMDsLQRKhmUEA9rM/0

Comment: Did my solution not work for you?

Comment: Another question @azcc , what if on the last condition `select color where id="2"` there are more than 1 result that don't have any replacement? Should it return all of the id or the next one after the searched id or the max id after the searched id?

Comment: @azcc I think your word "funnel" is not clear to most of the commentors. What you're actually doing is a chain, where the `replaced_by` column is the link between rows.

Comment: @tcadidot0 How can there be more than 1? You start with row 2, follow it to row 3, follow that to row 4, then you're done because `replaced_with` is null.

Comment: @Barmar , I'm assuming that since `id=1 replaced_by is NULL` then it's possible that along the line after id=2 there will be some id where `replaced_by is NULL` as well. If we look at the example query `SELECT color WHERE id=2` does not specifically mention `type` so I assume that it was suppose to return the next id(s) that have `replaced_by is NULL` regardless of it's type. Let's say id=6 with type=color also have `replaced_by is NULL`, should that be returned in the result as well? Or should it return only the immediate id after the searched condition?

Comment: @tcadidot0 It's a linked list. You start with a particular ID, follow the chain of `replaced_by` links, until you get to one with NULL.

Comment: Ok @Barmar , now I understand. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the last replacement as requested:

```
SELECT id, type, color, replaced_by 
FROM `tbl1`
WHERE id = (SELECT max(replaced_by) FROM `tbl1`)
```

> the `` WHERE id = (SELECT max(replaced_by) FROM `tbl1`) `` finds the highest `replaced_by` and returns the `id` associated with it. This is how it returns the *last* `replaced_by` as requested.

Comment: This seems to assume that `replaced_by` is always higher than `id`.

Comment: I'll add more detail to the answer :)

Comment: @Mech this only returns a single row 4, because the max replaced_by value is 4.

Comment: I'm missing what you are looking for then. That would be the last one and matches your desired output.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where replaced_by is null;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. But how does this follow the `replaced_by` chain? The last part of the question asked how to get the final row in the chain when you start with `id=2`

Comment: @Barmar . . . The OP says that s/he might be overcomplicating the question.  All the returned values have `replaced_by` as `NULL`.  It is not clear that anything needs to be "followed".

Comment: What about the last example, where they want to start from a specific `id=2`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff what Barmar said... the "following" or chaining is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: @azcc . . . I would say that your question does not do a good job of explaining what you really want to do.